# Adding orders to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add orders from an ecommerce website  into mysql but it seems only the last product gets inserted. This is the PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['suborder'])) {

    $itemname = $_POST['item_name_{itemname}'];
    $itemprice = $_POST['item_price_{itemprice}'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity_{quantity}'];
    $subtot = $_POST['subtot_{subtot}'];


    $poof = $con->command("INSERT INTO orders(product_name,price,quantity,sub_total) VALUES(:itemname,:itemprice,:quantity,:subtot) ");

    $poof->bindParam(':itemname', $itemname);
    $poof->bindParam(':itemprice', $itemprice);
    $poof->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
    $poof->bindParam(':subtot', $subtot);


    $poof->execute();


}
```

Comment: Only the last product gets inserted? Is there a loop somewhere? Multiple products? I dont see any errors in your code at the moment.

Comment: If you have one or more products in your cart then create a loop to generate list of `INSERT` statements or batch insert statement to save the data to DB.

Comment: yes only the last product gets inserted and i dont have a loop in my code

Comment: The question is, do you want that? Or what **do** you want to happen? Your question is very unclear as you don't state a question, just a fact that doesn't have any further alignment of knowledge.

Comment: The problem is, you (probably) have multiple items but you save them as 1 variable so they get overwritten. You (probably) have to just change the name of your inputs from: `item_name_{itemname}` to `item_name_{itemname}[]` and loop over the result while inserting.

Comment: @Loko Always fun, this guessing game, isn't it?

Comment: @Nytrix Yeah it actually is. Al though sometimes I just waste time typing a solution and then they just have a completely different problem that no one would ever find in their code since it's not in the code they provided.

Comment: Yeah i want that to loop throught and get the multiple products

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using a reference in the foreach:

foreach ($reindex as $key => &$value) {  //pass $value as a reference to the array item
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);  // bind the variable to the statement
}